# OpenCV VideoCapture error: VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: opencv

I have been trying to read videos from a file in Java using OpenCV. I am running OpenCV 4.0.0 on Ubuntu. Currently I have been trying to do so as follows: 
`VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture("/home/gkammer/Downloads/test.mp4");` 
However, this is giving me the error message `VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Inappropriate ioctl for device`.
I have already tried rebuilding OpenCV with FFMPEG like many similar questions recommend, but I still get the error. When I ran cmake this was the relevant output: 
`Video I/O:
DC1394:                      YES (ver 2.2.5)
FFMPEG:                      YES
avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.107.100)
avformat:                  YES (ver 57.83.100)
avutil:                    YES (ver 55.78.100)
swscale:                   YES (ver 4.8.100)
avresample:                YES (ver 3.7.0)
GStreamer:                   NO
v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h` 
Any suggestions for how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to read a *.mp4* video with **OpenCV 4.0.1-34-g78da67947** and **GStreamer 1.14.1** with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

To enable this video backend, install gstreamer required dependencies with:

`sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good`

Then recompile OpenCV with `WITH_GSTREAMER` flag on.

I also have issues reading mp4 video or rtsp stream with **V4L** or **DC1364** even if I have compiled OpenCV with the correct options :

```
"  Video I/O:
"
"    DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
"
"    FFMPEG:                      NO
"
"      avcodec:                   NO
"
"      avformat:                  NO
"
"      avutil:                    NO
"
"      swscale:                   NO
"
"      avresample:                NO
"
"    GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.1)
"
"    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

If someone has a solution to this problem (specifically the DC1394 backend).

Answer (score 0):

If gstreamer is not installed or there are problems with installing with `sudo apt-get gstreamer-xxx`, try `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

I also have faced with this problem, then I have paid attention to the OpenCV compilation headers, installed almost all packages listed in [official docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) (except libjasper), cmake made it without WITH_GSTREAMER but with WITH_FFMPEG=ON and got videos with different files extensions(avi, mkv) playing on C++ and Python in Ubuntu 18.04.

Besides, explicit WITH_GSTREAMER=ON does not set flag GSTREAMER to YES.